# all users executing a certain command. grep

Tags: shell, grep

I'd like to find all the names of the users that are executing a certain command given as a parameter.
grep must be used.
I have tried: ps aux | grep $1 | cut -d" " -f1, but it's not the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

```
/usr/ucb/ps aux | awk '/<your_command_as_parameter>/{print $1}'|sort -u
```

for eg:

```
> /usr/ucb/ps aux | awk '/rlogin/{print $1}' | sort -u
```

Comment: @sarathi it also includes the user who executes /usr/ucb/ps aux | awk '/<your_command_as_parameter>/{print $1}'|sort -u, but he is not executing the command given as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're looking for this.

```
# cat test.sh
ps aux | grep $1 | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}'
# ./test.sh bash
root
root
root
```

Comment: That mostly works unless you're looking for people running `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick to getting the information for processes but not the process that's searching for the process, which is to make the name into a regex.  For example, if you're searching for `ls`, make the search term into `grep '[l]s'`.  This works unless you're searching for `grep` itself, or a single-letter command name.

This is the `procname` script I use; it works with most POSIX shells:

```
#! /bin/ksh
#
#   @(#)$Id: procname.sh,v 1.3 2008/12/16 07:25:10 jleffler Exp $
#
#   List processes with given name, avoiding the search program itself.
#
#   If you ask it to list 'ps', it will list the ps used as part of this
#   script; if you ask it to list 'grep', it will list the grep used as
#   part of this process.  There isn't a sensible way to avoid this.  On
#   the other hand, if you ask it to list httpd, it won't list the grep
#   for httpd.  Beware metacharacters in the first position of the
#   process name.

case "$#" in
1)
    x=$(expr "$1" : '\(.\).*')
    y=$(expr "$1" : '.\(.*\)')
    ps -ef | grep "[$x]$y"
    ;;
*)
    echo "Usage: $0 process" 1>&2
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

In `bash`, you could use the variable substringing operations to avoid the `expr` commands:

```
case "$#" in
1)  ps -ef | grep "[${1:0:1}]${1:1}"
    ;;
*)
    echo "Usage: $0 process" 1>&2
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

Both of these run `ps -ef`; you can use `ps aux` if you prefer.  The search for the 'command' name is not constrained to the command portion of the command, so you could use `procname root` to find processes run by root.  The match is also not constrained to a full word; you could consider `grep -w` for that (a GNU `grep` extension).

The output of these is the full line of data from `ps`; if you want just the user (the first field), then pipe the output to `awk '{print $1}' | sort -u`.